# How to configure Jenkins Job for running TesNG suite file

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, testng, pom.xml

I have TestNG framework and I am trying to run test suites using Jenkins Job.

Gave git repo location as `gitadmin@repos:company-name-automation.git` and goal as `test  -Dsuite_name=Suite_file_name`,  but its not finding pom.xml and under Root POM option, it says:

> No such file: 'pom.xml'

Tried to delete workspace before running job, but still seeing same error.

Comment: Do you have a `pom.xml` in your git repo?

Comment: yes, i have. do i need remove ".git" from repo location?

Comment: It should work with or without the .git. You can check if that works manually (outside of Jenkins) by cloning the repo and running the tests yourself.

Comment: it works manually in eclipse. cloned on different machines, its working there.

Comment: Then if it doesn't work in Jenkins, may be HOME isn't defined when the Jenkins process is running (since git will look for ssh keys in `%HOME%/.ssh/`) For Windows, you can see the chat I did earlier today: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65360/discussion-between-vonc-and-java-beginner

Comment: thanks @VonC. i created another job in jenkins and it is working there after i removed ".git" from repo url. but still initial job is failing with exact same config. this is error "method method_name in class class-name cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: resolved error "method method_name in class class-name cannot be applied to given types " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116931/jenkins-error-actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ-in-length/27138163#27138163