# Jenkins : [ERROR] actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

i have created mavenized TestNG project. it is working fine in eclipse. but when i run TestSuite in Jenkins, i am seeing compiler error. i had to remove some overloaded methods. but now i am facing this error for non-overloaded method.

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /apps/jenkins/workspace/qa-tax-svc-automation/src/test/java/addressVerificationService/OverriddenAddressVerificationServiceTest.java:[62,33] error: method ExecuteGetCall in class OMSD_Util cannot be applied to given types;

[ERROR]  actual and formal argument lists differ in length

/apps/jenkins/workspace/qa-tax-svc-automation/src/test/java/addressVerificationService/UnverifiedAddressVerificationServiceTest.java:[70,33] error: method ExecuteGetCall in class OMSD_Util cannot be applied to given types;

[ERROR]  actual and formal argument lists differ in length

/apps/jenkins/workspace/qa-tax-svc-automation/src/test/java/pricingService/PricingServiceDataDrivenTest.java:[94,24] error: method CreateTaxServiceURI in class UriGenerator cannot be applied to given types;
.
.
.
.

Comment: error seems to be quite explanatory if you know your classes and methods.

Comment: thanks Juned, but the same code works on local. no compile or run-time error. i am unable to understand "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: your test case may be using some environment variable, which is different on your local and test bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks lker Aguayo. i changed java version on my local, but that didnt help. Finally in jenkins for 'Goals and OPtions' i gave value 'clean test -Dsuite_name=WS_Suite'.

previously i was only giving 'test -Dsuite_name=WS_Suite'.

Answer (score 0):

The versions of Java and Maven, are the same in the Jenkins and in your local? If there are differents, try in your local with Jenkins versions and see if the problem comes. It could be a first step to discard possible causes.